# navigationoptions won't work in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm following this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgg1HidN4mQ&list=PLy9JCsy2u97lNUL3e3R-uoMQv5GDvf22T

The guy in the tutorial are using TabNavigator, but that is not longer the right way to do It, so I'm using createBottomNavigator instead.

Here is my code of the MainScreen component

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

import ProfileTab from './AppTabNavigator/ProfileTab'
import LikesTab from './AppTabNavigator/LikesTab'
import SearchTab from './AppTabNavigator/SearchTab'
import AddMediaTab from './AppTabNavigator/AddMediaTab'
import HomeTab from './AppTabNavigator/HomeTab'

import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

import { Icon } from 'native-base'


class MainScreen extends React.Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        headerLeft: <Icon name="ios-camera-outline" style={{paddingLeft: 10}} />,
        title: "Instagram",
        headerRight: <Icon name="ios-send-outline" style={{paddingRight: 10}}/>
    }
}

// export default MainScreen;
export default createBottomTabNavigator({
    HomeTab: HomeTab,
    SearchTab: SearchTab,
    AddMediaTab: AddMediaTab,
    LikesTab: LikesTab,
    ProfileTab: ProfileTab
})

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex:1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
})
```

My problem Is that navigationoptions won't work. They don't show up when I start the application. I can guess that this has something to do with the use of createBottomNavigator?

Comment: your MainScreen isn't render anything. Btw, you can use `createBottomTabNavigator` in `react-navigator` v2 in the same way with `TabNavigator` in v1, it isn't reason for this error.

Comment: @TuấnTrầnDuy: What should I render then? As you can see in the tutorial, he is rendering AppTabNavigator, but i'm not using that. So what should I render either to get It to work?

Comment: Ah, you export directly the tab navigator, so you need to place `navigationOptions` config to `createBottomTabNavigator` like `createBottomTabNavigator(routeConfig, navigationOptions)`

Answer (score 0):

I made a snack on expo.io to do what I think you're trying to do. It's a little unclear because you're trying to set a left and right icon for the header, but tab navigators don't have headers.

I've nested a stack navigator on the settings screen in this example, and you can see how I'm using a single components static navigation options to override the "global" navigation options for the whole stack navigator.

Here's the [snack](https://snack.expo.io/HJ0Zi6x4X).

If you want the header on every tab no matter what, just reverse the nesting and put your tab navigator inside a stack navigator. Here's a snack for that, too.

https://snack.expo.io/rk3hoalVm